# Recover not properly burned DVD from camcoder

Tags: video, data-recovery, dvd, burning, camera

Can anybody suggest to me any good, and preferably free, software - working on Vista / 7 -  for recovering content from DVD disks?

A few DVD-R VOB files cannot be read from disk by Windows. Probably the camera failed to burn it correctly.

What I want to achieve is to skip a few invalid frames in VOB files and recreate proper a MPEG stream -  without re-encoding the whole stream and losing the quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want without a doubt is [ISOBuster](http://www.isobuster.com/) - it's IMHO the best optical disc recovery program. That should be able to get any data on the disc off it and into a usable format.

IF your VOB files are still corrupt you can try using [FFMpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to reencode the video.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem similar to yours, 3-4 years a go, with a sony camera, so the following advices did work for me.

First, look for an application to get the corrupted data from your dvd like said by [Mark Pim](https://superuser.com/questions/152106/recover-not-properly-burned-dvd-from-camcoder/154032#154032). ISOBuster is really the best app in my opinion to recover data.

After recovering your data from disc, **backup it** to do the video editing only in a copy (so if you need to do more editing you already recovered the files from your damaged dvd-r disc avoiding data re-extraction).

After the backup, use [VideoRedo](http://www.videoredo.com/en/index.htm) to fix your vob mpeg2 files **without reencoding**.

> With VideoReDo's perfected smart
>   rendering technology you can edit
>   again and again without degrading any
>   of your precious videos.

(These are all windows based approaches)

Answer (score 1):

You might give a try to [Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier](http://www.roadkil.net/program.php/P29/Unstoppable%20Copier):

> Recovers files from disks with
>   physical damage. Allows you to copy
>   files from disks with problems such as
>   bad sectors, scratches or that just
>   give errors when reading data. The
>   program will attempt to recover every
>   readable piece of a file and put the
>   pieces together. Using this method
>   most types of files can be made
>   useable even if some parts of the file
>   were not recoverable in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea on the format of VOB files and if they can be recovered, but before anything else, I would try [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org) as I have had success reading from various other sorts of corrupted media files.

Answer (score 0):

In the unlikely event that ISOBuster doesn't work out for you, I can also suggest a program called ProjectX.  You can strip the raw mpeg+audio out of VOBs with it as well.

[Videohelp](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/ProjectX) has links to the sourceforge page as well as compiled and portable versions.